# Swift Change UIContainerView height and width

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview, container-view

I have two ContainerView which are placed above each other,for example ContainerA is front of ContainerB.

When a Button tapped ContainerA width and height should change to a smaller size, then ContainerB will be shown.

How can I change height and width of a container view using swift instead of story board? does it have something like transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change its frame:

```
let currentContainerViewFrame = containerView?.frame
currentContainerViewFrame?.width -= 200
currentContainerViewFrame?.height -= 200
containerView?.frame = currentContainerViewFrame
```

or work with its transform property:

```
containerView?.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.7, 0.7)
```

Comment: it doesn't have something like transform?

Comment: it has. you could also use that: `containerView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)`

Comment: it says: Use of unresolved identifier 'containerView' when I write the first line

Comment: of course you have to replace it with the reference to your containerview whose size you want to change!

Comment: I don't know what is the reference, cause when I Ctrl + drag and drop from the container to the ViewController.swift I can not declare it to work with and nothing happens

Comment: would you like to share your project so i can take a look?

Comment: yeah sure: andre.slotta@gmail.com

Comment: I have Sent dude ;-)

Comment: can you explain again what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: if you check the project you can see I am trying to make a sidebar menu. I want when the user press menu button the second container shows up. now it will be shown but the buttons in it are disable

Comment: glad i could help. :)